# Replace folder name does not work

Tags: c#, replace

I want to able to search in a folder with all subfolders. then if its name contains a specific word, I change or remove it.
For example

```
movie\movie2018\movie2018-2-10
```

to

```
movie\movie2015\movie2015-2-10
```

I used the blow code

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories); 
foreach (var folder in dirs) 
{ 
    if (folder.Contains("2018")) 
        dirs.ToString().Replace("2018", "2015"); 
}
```

it gets folder's name but does not change it. Could you tell me where is my mistake?

**Solution:**

```
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(myRootPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (var folder in dirs)
        {
            if (folder.ToLower().Contains("oldchar"))
                Directory.Move(folder, folder.ToLower().Replace("oldchar", "newchar"));
        }
```

Comment: It is expected that Stack Overflow questions demonstrate a minimal amount of research and effort.  Please [edit] your question to include the code that you have written, as well as a specific, answerable question about the part where you are stuck.

Comment: There are plenty of utilities that already do this; why can't you use one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try to iterate over Directory folders?

```
public void Rename(string root_path)
{
     var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root_path);

     foreach(var folder in dirs) {
        if (folder.contains("spcefic_word")
               // voila! rename
     Rename(folder);      
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it completely renames folder names. I want to replace a string with another.

Comment: well when you find a folder that contains that string (say: folder_img01), just do a string.replace("_img01","_newname");